# Android Studio cannot open Android project with Kotlin DSL

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have converted one of our Android projects from the old Groovy `settings.gradle` and `build.gradle` files to the new Kotlin DSL, i. e. `settings.gradle.kts` and `build.gradle.kts`.

While "it works on my machine" - in particular: the original project I converted from Groovy to Kotlin works fine in its original directory - all my co-workers are unable to open the project when they clone the repo. Importantly, neither can I open the project myself (with the same AS installation on the same machine) when I clone the repo to some other directory. So, I suspect there is some additional detail missing in some configuration file but I cannot seem to figure out which...

Details:

- When I just use `File > Open...` and then select the project folder, I only get the error message "The project 'xxx' is not a Gradle-based project"
- When I instead go through `Import Project (Gradle, Eclipse ADT, etc.)` and then select `Import project from external model` and `Android Gradle` Android Studio will create an empty `build.gradle` file and fail with the error message "ERROR: Plugin with id 'com.android.library' not found." Deleting the `build.gradle` just goes back to the error message I described in the first bullet point.

I am aware of [this Github issue](https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl/issues/1166), which seems to describe the same problem, but it's been very quiet and I thought someone around here must have figured out a solution to this...

Oh, command line builds work everywhere - this is purely an Android Studio problem.

**UPDATE**: When I *copy* the whole project to a new folder (instead of *cloning* the repository) I can open it without any problems. So, am I correct in assuming that there *must* be something inside the folder - but not in Git - that makes it work?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was able to 'fix' it by deleting the `.idea` directory and reopening the project. The `.idea` directory is usually not committed in git but I guess copying the directory invalidates the directory structures in the files within the .idea directory.

The whole bug is easily reproducible when you click on `File` > `Re-import Gradle project`.

Comment: Ah, that's very helpful, thanks! You are right, `File > Re-import Gradle project` breaks even a working project by creating an empty `build.gradle` file - exactly like in my second bullet point. Also, I must admit that I have _some_ files from the `.idea` folder in Git, namely stuff related to the code style... I would have thought this is permissible or even sensible... I can also reproduce your "fix": 1.) clone 2.) `rm -rf .idea` 3.) Open project in AS seems to work consistently... the only problem then is that I lose all my custom configuration in the `.idea` folder...

Comment: Worked perfectly. Just needed to recreate the app configuration though.

Comment: Since this workaround seems to be the best we can do at the moment, I am marking this as the accepted answer.

Comment: THANK YOU! This also fixes `New Gradle sync not supported due to containing Kotlin modules` issues.

Answer (score 8):

@Boni2k answer does not work for me.

I have to rename the root `build.gradle.kts` back to `build.gradle`, fix the syntax error, sync the project (which works fine immediately), and rename the file back to `build.gradle.kts`. Then the error is gone and I can sync the project successfully.

What I did to raise the error was that I moved the project to a different folder, and rename the project.